# Query doesnt insert to database when using "/" for concatenation

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query='insert into shopping_tbl (itemcode,name)values ("'$num."/".$barcode.","."$name"'")';
```

the itemcode wont be inserted because of the "/". however if i use "-" instead of "/" it will be inserted however i need to use "/"

sample data: itemcode: 23/xxdd22, name: watchx

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: The question definitely needs more context. Column types, error message, the final `$query` string etc.

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error with that I think.

Comment: That they should @JonStirling but they either didn't tell us what it was, or aren't checking for them properly.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Or didn't give us the right code.

Comment: this isn't in production right?

Comment: it has no error. it just dont insert on the database. however if i use "-" in concatenating them, it will be inserted

Comment: I'm just wondering "why" you want to do this. Believe me, this would be easier if you were to first concatenate both variables, *then* use that new variable assignment in the query.

Comment: You're not completing the quoting between the barcode, comma, and name. This is a good place where using prepared statements and parameter binding would eliminate quoting issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a parameterized statement, that people are talking about in the comments.

```
$params = [ 'itemcode' => "$num/$barcode", 'name' => $name ];
$sql = 'insert into shopping_tbl (itemcode, name) values (:itemcode, :name)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Stop struggling with quotes-within-quotes in SQL, you'll only give yourself eyestrain.

Comment: I didn't see your answer; I was busy typing up mine. More power to ya Bill ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments; this would be easier if you were to first concatenate both variables, then use that new variable assignment in the query, rather than fighting with munging a bunch of unnecessary quotes/dots, etc.

I.e.:

```
$new = $num."/".$barcode;
```

Then do:

```
values ('$new','$name')
```

Given that the `itemcode` column is VARCHAR and not an INT; that is unknownst to us.

Although using a prepared statement would be safer and better in a case like this, should user input be involved.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 0):

omitting that your solution isn't perfect. You have problem with the quotation marks. on my local database this works correctly.

```
$query="insert into shopping_tbl (itemcode,name)values ('".$num."/".$barcode."','".$name."')";
```